# Visual Studio 2013 RC Missing Short Cuts

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2013

I previously documented error where 2013 RC would not install until I installed 2012 due to a MVC error.  While installing 2012 did allow for successful installation, I only have the short cut to Blend.

Is there some way to get/find short cuts for the Visual Studio 2013 devenv and all tools?

Comment: Since you have successfully installed 2013 RC, you should be able to find and create shortcut from the location below location? (This assume you have installed in this location)                  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

Comment: Sure, I did that but there are other programs and tools.